# Extract text two words to the LEFT of Delimiter value within string

Tags: excel, extract, formula

This question is not a duplicate to a previously posted Excel question, instead this question is seeking to Extract Words LEFT of the Delimiter; whereas the previously posted question Extracts words to the Right of Delimiter.

Using MS Excel, I would like to extract two words (three spaces) to the LEFT of delimiter value "^", including extracting the identifier word with attached/associated with delimiter "^"

EXAMPLE: Cell A2

Johnny and I were planning on going to the movie to see ^Batman Returns, but it was to late.

Results: Cell B2

to see ^Batman

Comment: @DirkReichel, now you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some better solution but here is what i have:

```
=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1;FIND("^",A1))-1),FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^",LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("^",A1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("^",A1))," ",""))-2))+1,9999)
```

the core is : `LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("^",A1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("^",A1))," ",""))`
it counts the spaces from string start till your delimeter, then replacing the `count - 2` space# with anoter delimeter to find your start `FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^",LEN(...)-LEN(...)-2))+1` doing this for a string that ends earlier `LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1;FIND("^",A1))-1)` (you dont need to do the long term a second time)

Answer (score 0):

A non-VBA formula approach is possible (possibly as an array formula) but would be like making a sculpture with a butter knife. Here is a VBA function which can be used as a UDF:

```
Function ExtractLeft(str As String, delim As String, words As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim left_words As String, right_word As String

    A = Split(str, delim)
    right_word = A(1)
    right_word = Split(right_word)(0)
    right_word = delim & right_word
    left_words = A(0)
    A = Split(Trim(left_words))
    n = UBound(A)
    For i = n To n - words + 1 Step -1
        right_word = A(i) & " " & right_word
    Next i
    ExtractLeft = right_word
End Function
```

The advantage of the VBA approach is that you can easily change both the delimiter and the number of words to extract:

[image]